# commit compiled webpack assets or compile at production server?

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore

I have a setup with Symfony and webpack encore. This application is deployed to heroku with git. I am not sure if I should commit the compiled webpack .js files or if I should move encore and all webpack dependencies from devDependencies to dependencies so that the compilation could be done at the production server.

Which one is best?

Comment: I'm interested of an answer. I used to compile assets in my production server with assetic:dump. I read on the doc this practice is not recommended. I'd like to be able to dump my dev assets in something like public/build/dev and add this folder to my .gitignore file and dump the prod assets in public/build but i didnt manage to do it. An other solution is to compile prod assets in my dev environnement, add public/build to .gitignore and use filezilla to add assets files in my prod server. An ugly solution is to remove public/build from gitignore when i need to push new assets on the server...